# Swift customize TableView trailing action view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a `TableView` with a `trailingSwipeAction`.

This is my code for it:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {

    let deleteAction = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete".localized()) {[unowned self] _, _, completionHandler in
            let selectedUser = self.friendsDataSourceArray[indexPath.section]
            self.friendsDataSourceArray.remove(at: indexPath.section)
            let indexSet = IndexSet(arrayLiteral: indexPath.section)
            self.theTableView.deleteSections(indexSet, with: .fade)
            self.theTableView.reloadData()
            DataHandler.removeFriend(friendId: selectedUser.uid)
            completionHandler(true)
        }
        deleteAction.backgroundColor = .redCustom
        deleteAction.image = UIImage(systemName: "person.fill.badge.minus")
        let configuration = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [deleteAction])
        configuration.performsFirstActionWithFullSwipe = true
        return configuration

}
```

And this is how it looks like:

[image]

**This is how I would like it to look like:**

[image]

Two things are wrong with mine.

**1.** there is no `inset shadow`

**2.** it is not aligning with the rounded corner of my `cell`.

Any idea how I can achieve that?

Comment: I think that you might have to "extend" a little your cell on the left (outside its initial bounds) to have the desired effect. Might trigger it only when swipe occurs.

Comment: @Larme how would I do that?